# Can I set the children props in a react component from its parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible in react to do something like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            children: [<div/>, <div/>],
            comp: ''
        };
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        this.setState({
            comp: <SomeComponent children={this.state.children}/>
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.comp === '' ? this.state.children : this.state.comp}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

When I try to do something similar to this I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` so I assume the answer is no, but I figure there has to be some way considering

```
<SomeComponent>
    <div/>
</SomeComponet>
```

where `<SomeCompent/>` renders a `<div/>`, is valid.  However in this particular case I get the same error doing that, but if you look at something like React-Bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io/, it has to be possible.

Comment: That's a good idea, if it wasn't for the fact that's not at all what I'm asking, I'm not looking to pass state to a child, I'm looking to dynamically pass **children elements** to a parent, in the parent of the parent.  However, I know for a fact you can write *JSX* in a `setState()`.  *JSX* not html, is an object, therefore it can be treated as any other kind of data.

Comment: yeah you could, the thing with html tags you need to convert them into string then only you can pass it as variable to state, probably you can use eval or iso to render the html into parents elements https://github.com/goatslacker/iso. But I believe you trying to reinventing the wheel

Comment: ummmmmm no.  I don't think you understand what JSX is and how it works. This isn't html. Please do some research before you comment things like that: https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

Comment: I wrote react/flux(alt-reflux) applications already, probably I don't understand your question, but I thought is not possible, if that's what you asking in the first place. But since you so adamant about the possibility why not come out with prove of concept on your site.

Comment: You may have written react apps before sure, but you can write react apps without jsx.  But as I am saying, Jsx is treated as an object, as you can see in https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html for example. Where if you look at the source, you may pass components as props of each other, as well as into functions, which may set a state attribute to some JSX.

Comment: you can write react apps without jsx, you could always use traceur or babel to do the transpiling. I never see anyone code react apps and pass html elements as state before, it always wrote within render state, if that's what you asking and your links is bad link to prove your idea exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90249/discussion-between-christian-grabowski-and-syarul).

Comment: if a function could return JSX, JSX is therefore data, and thus `this.setState({something: <Something/>});` is just as valid as `this.setState({something: {}});`

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to pass html tags as state? I'm not saying is bad, but there's always a better solution to what you asking. Let's say a child component passing a state Boolean true or false to parent component( Flux - Action by child component pass to store, parent components can pick up the state with onChange event). With that you could invoke the parent element to render different view.

```
_onChange: function() {
    this.setState(this._getStateFromStores());
},

render: function() {
    var view;

    if (this.state.childAction) {
        view = <SomethingTrue/> ;
    }
    if (!this.state.childAction) {
        view = <SomethingFalse/> ;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {view}
        </div>
);
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I'm asking.  I'm asking to be able to modify this https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html from the parent of the target component. So the parent of the parent component sets the children.  The fact that I'm setting it as state is because what the children of the target is, is based on the state of the parent's parent component.

Comment: Basically, can I conditionally have a component that when it is not present still have the same (as in a === a, not a == a) child element present as I would with the parent present.